# How to unit test a function whose output can vary?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a function that fetches latest data from a URL based on given inputs. How do I write a unit test for this function given that the output is not fixed and might change every day?

```
def get_data_from_url(param1, param2):
    url = f"https://some-service/get_data/param1={param1}&param2={param2}"
    resp = requests.get(url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
    something = resp.json()['something']
    if something.match(pattern):
        ...
        return some_value
    elif something.match(some_other_pattern):
        ...
        return some_other_value
    else:
        return something
```

I'm using pytest for my unit tests.

Comment: So what do you want to test?

Comment: _Test doubles_. You don't want a unit test making a network request even if the response _won't_ change, because they're orders of magnitude slower and potentially flaky.

Comment: In unit tests you have to define some criteria to evaluate if the code passes or doesn't pass the test (eg: empty output vs non-empty output). If the output can change you have to come up with some test that will pass/fail according to your needs

Comment: Are you really hard-coding the URL in your code? It should be a variable from somewhere anyway, but that then makes mocking it easier too.

Comment: Also, if your function did only one thing that would be easier too. `construct_url('hostname,parameter1,parameter2')->url`, `get_json_from_URL(url)->json` and `get_something_from_json(json)->something` .. then you isolate the untestable code into a function which only really does ' requests.get'.  see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514953/should-i-write-unit-test-for-everything#:~:text=The%20answer%20to%20the%20more%20general%20question%20is,also%20documents%20the%20intended%20usage%20of%20the%20interfaces.

Comment: My example was overly simplified. There are some other operations that are performed on the url response before returning. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use mock. Either a standard mock or a [`requests_mock`](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```py
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_with_simple_mock(self):
        fake_result = collections.namedtuple("Response", ("status_code", "json"))(
            200, lambda: {"something": "somevalue"}
        )
        with mock.patch("requests.get", return_value=fake_result):
            self.assertEquals(
                requests.get("https://some-service/get_data/").json()["something"],
                "somevalue",
            )

    def test_with_requests_mock(self):
        with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
            m.get("https://some-service/get_data/", text='{"something": "somevalue"}')
            self.assertEquals(
                requests.get("https://some-service/get_data/").json()["something"],
                "somevalue",
            )
```